# Spring data JPA - Do not hard code password in XML file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am writing a Spring Jar (Without Spring boot)  which connects to database. Almost all the tutorials which I saw connects to Database using the spring XML and the password is hard coded in the XML file. 
This is in no way allowed in production environment and way out of standards in terms of security.

Can someone please help me if there is a way to inject password from a method call which inturn retrieves the password from a secured vault and provides the password to datasource object in runtime.

something like below.

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres" />
    <property name="username" value="postgres" />
    <property name="password" value=getPasswordfromSecureVault("username") />
    <property name="suppressClose" value="true" />
    <jdbc:initialize-database  >
    <jdbc:script location="create-tables.sql"/>
    </jdbc:initialize-database>
```

Comment: Use application prop file. When you start the app, it will search it config folder under the current directory, then current dir, then classpath. So put the prop there. Or you can start the app with vm arg spring.config.location where you can add the file path.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the spring boot tag that you have, I'll assume that you're using spring boot for your project. With spring boot, it is very easy to externalize configuration for your application. It also auto-configures your datasource with a connection pool if you use the starters they provide.

In your case, you could benefit from moving to using spring boot's [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config).
What that would allow you to do is to use an environment variable to configure your spring application. For example, to configure your password, use the environment variable `SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD`. You could also use the Java option `-Dspring.datasource.password=[password]` when starting the application, for example:
`java -jar -Dspring.datasource.password=password app.jar`

If using docker containers, the environment variable way is generally my go to as it's very straight forward for people to understand.

If you really want to configure the password from a method call, you can do that too using java configuration. Create a bean of type `DataSource` and Spring should pick it up and use it.

```
@Configuration
class AppConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
       String password = // Get your password
       return DataSourceBuilder.create().password(password).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Kiage,
Thanks very much for your suggestion !!!
Just have one question. Mine is not spring boot, just core spring. Does the method call which you provided using configuration annotation would still work ?? 
Please let me know , that will complete all doubts. Thanks !!!

Comment: @Saimuga, `DataSourceBuilder` is a spring boot api. With core spring, you may have to manually register a datasource instance. I would suggest you used spring boot if it's a new project. It removes the need for a lot of the boilerplate code you would have to write

Comment: Hi Kiage,

The only reason I didnt go for Spring boot is because of the below reason.

1. My requirement is to have a spring batch jar file which will invoke below command through to start and complete the batch. 
   I have added the command in the question. please check it.
2. If i run it as spring boot , I cannot use this command because it will not start the spring boot project main method (Which is mostly the entry point for any spring boot app). Therefore the application will not get started properly as a spring boot app.

Thats why I did not go for Spring Boot. please advise !!!

Comment: @Saimuga, spring boot has support for autoconfiguring spring batch. There's a spring batch starter available `spring-boot-starter-batch` https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-starter

Comment: Thanks very much for all your solutions Kiage !!! I will  use spring boot for my project.